# AVAssetExportSession is nil iPhone 7 - Plus Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, avfoundation

`AVAssetExportSession` works fine on iPhone 6 and below but not on iPhone 7, iPhone 7 Plus simulator. Xcode 8.0

This code `return nil` in exportSession, when is executed on iPhone 7 - Plus Simulator, but not in iPhone SE, iPhone 6s ... Simulator. Please find the below code for more information.

```
    NSURL *inputURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"example" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    AVURLAsset *assetAV = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:assetAV presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    NSAssert(exportSession != nil, @"AVAssetExportSession must not be nil");
```

It's a radar or there is something that I'm missing?.

> Sample project at:
>
> https://github.com/rafaelpereznajera/AVAssetExportSessionRadar

Comment: Do iPhone 7 contains example file ?

Comment: yes, the file exits, works fine on iPhone 6. You can check the sample project on github.

Comment: That seems broken. Although `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` works...

Answer (score 0):

> It's a bug.
>
> It's fixed in Xcode 8.1 beta.

Xcode 8.1 beta [AVAssetExportSession allExportPresets] iPhone 7 Simulator now returns:

```
AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080,
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality,
AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A,
AVAssetExportPreset640x480,
AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160,
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720,
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality,
AVAssetExportPreset960x540
```

Xcode 8.0 [AVAssetExportSession allExportPresets] iPhone 7 Simulator returns an empty array.