# AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets() returning empty list

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator

AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets() returning empty list on the new 2018 iPhone simulator (XS, XS Max and XR). Also it seems impossible to set up an AVAssetExportSession.

Does anyone know if this functionality has been lost or is it a bug?

I'm using:

- Xcode 10 or Xcode 10.1 Beta
- Macbook Pro 2015
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

All the other iOS simulators (iPads or iPhones with iOS  9, 10, 11 or 12) return a list like this or with a few entries missing:

[Link to output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yvaP.png)

using this code:

```
let presets = AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets()
for preset in presets
{
    Swift.print (preset)
}
```

Comment: This isn't the first time a new Xcode release has had missing AVAssetExportSession presets, so it's likely a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665106/5256012